# MvcMailer not working on production

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-5, mailer

I had my `web.config` mail section like that:

```
<smtp from="mail@gmail.com">
    <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mail@gmail.com" password="pwd" />
</smtp>
```

Tested locally,
but I got an error on *production*(i am using shared hosting environment):

```
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

I googled I find out possible [solution](http://learnlinq.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/smtp-server-requires-secure-connection.html),
 so I changed my configuration as:

```
<smtp from="mail@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mail@gmail.com" password="pwd" defaultCredentials="true"/>
</smtp>
```

And now I got this error:

```
he SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ko10sm114859924pbd.38 - gsmtp
```

How can I fix that?

I also tied to add delivery method:

```
<smtp from="mail@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
            <network enableSsl="true" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="mail@gmail.com" password="pwd" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    </smtp>
```

But ho way.

**UPDATE**

I just checked my gmail and find out email from google

> Someone recently used your password to try to sign in to your Google
>   Account xxxxxxx@gmail.com. This person was using an application such as
>   an email client or mobile device.
>
> We prevented the sign-in attempt in case this was a hijacker trying to
>   access your account. Please review the details of the sign-in attempt:
>
> Monday, January xxx.xxx UTC  IP Address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Location: Unknown

So may be it is the reason why email send not working on production.
Because it is a new location and when you sign in from a new location on `gmail` you should answer security questions. So it make scene then why email is not working. 
So i am looking now how to unblock that locaton/ip address on `gmail` if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried sending a manual email (using the `SmtpClient` class directly) with the same settings? That would at least eliminate one possibility.

Comment: If it helps, here's a Gist of some code I used to use: https://gist.github.com/tiesont/8280201

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<smtp from="mail@gmail.com">
```

to this:

```
<smtp from="mail@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
```

---

Edit: I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477055/the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authenticated), hope it helps.

---

Edit 2: Other solutions:

- [asp.net The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518122/asp-net-the-smtp-server-requires-a-secure-connection-or-the-client-was-not-authe)
- set `defaultCredentials="true"` to `false`

Comment: Too bad. Do you use 2-factor authentication for gmail?

Comment: It is working locally. No am not having `2f auth` with gmail.

Comment: Ofcourse, my bad. See the link in my edit, maybe it's an IIS setting.

Comment: I am on shared hosting env on production. I tested locally on both IIS and IIS express. The email was sending without any ssl settings on server.